# How to customize django-filter DateTimeFromToRangeFilter

Tags: django, django-filter

I have django-filter class with `DateTimeFromToRangeFilter`

And im looking for way to custom that in my template like split `form.work_date` on 2 sides or this is not possible?

filters.py

```
class PresenceDateFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    work_date = DateTimeFromToRangeFilter(
        widget=django_filters.widgets.RangeWidget(
            attrs={'type': 'date', 'class': 'form-control'},
        ))

    class Meta:
        model = PresenceDetailInfo
        fields = ('presence_info__counter_presence',
                  'work_date',
                  )
```

template.html

```
{% render_field form.work_date %}
```